# Checking if a word is a Palindrome or not

Tags: java

So when I'm running this code with any word, it is always returning false. The first String accepts the word, and then it's changed to lower case. Then I'm building a new String out of it to compare it to another string that is appended as the reverse of the original word. Am I not seeing something, or can you tell me what's wrong with it?

```js
public class Palindromes 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  int count = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
  {
   System.out.print(isPalindrome(args[i]) + " ");
  }
 }
 public static boolean isPalindrome(String s)
 {
  String str = s.toLowerCase();
  StringBuilder orig_str = new StringBuilder(str);
  StringBuilder revStr = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) 
  {
   revStr.append(orig_str.charAt(i));
  }
  boolean isPal = (revStr == orig_str);
  return isPal;
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing two distinct `StringBuilder` instances with == would always give you false, regardless of their content, since they are not the same instance.

Try `revStr.toString().equals(str)`

It seems that `StringBuilder` doesn't override `Object`'s `equals`, so you have to perform the `equals` on the `String`s that result from the `StringBuilder`s.

BTW, `StringBuilder` has a `reverse` method, so you can re-write your method in a single line :

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    return new StringBuilder(s.toLowerCase()).reverse().toString().equals(s.toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: Okay, I did change the boolean to revStr.equals(orig_str) but it still gives me a false value.

Comment: @Santo Fixed now. I didn't realize `StringBuilder` doesn't override `equals`.

Comment: I ended up with changing the revStr to a string after appending it. comparing them works fine now. Thanks a lot.